# oracle sequence question

Tags: oracle10g

There are two inserts in my trigger which is fired by an update. My Vendor_Hist table has a field called thID which is the primary key in Task_History table. thID gets its' value from mySeq.nextval.

```
INSERT INTO TASK_HISTORY
    ( thID, phId, LABOR, VERSION )         

    ( select   mySeq.NEXTVAL, mySeq2.CurrVal,  LABOR,  tmpVersion 
      from   tasks t     
      where t.project_id = :new.project_ID ); 

  select mySeq.currval into tmpTHID from dual; -- problem here! 

   INSERT INTO VENDOR_HIST 
    ( vhID, thID, Amount, Position, version  ) 

    ( select mySeq3.NEXTVAL,   tmpTHID,  
                Amount, Position, tmpVersion
      from   vendors v2, tasks t2     
      where  v2.myID =  t2.myID 
      and      t2.project_id = :new.project_ID );
```

Now, my problem is the tmpTHID always the latest value of mySeq.nextVal. So, if thID in task_history is 1,2,3, I get three inserts into vendor_hist table with 3,3,3. It has to be 1,2,3. I also tried

```
  INSERT INTO TASK_HISTORY
    ( thID, phId, LABOR, VERSION )         

    ( select   mySeq.NEXTVAL, mySe2.CurrVal,  LABOR,  tmpVersion 
      from   tasks t     
      where t.project_id = :new.project_ID )  returning thID into :tmpTHID;
```

but then I get a "warning compiled with errors" message when I execute the trigger. How do I make sure that the thID in first insert is also the same in my second insert?

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in (select * from tasks t
           where t.project_id = :new.project_id)
loop
  insert into task_history
  ( thID, phId, LABOR, VERSION )              
  values
  (mySeq.NEXTVAL, mySeq2.CurrVal,  i.LABOR,  i.tmpVersion);

  for each j in (select * from vendors v
                  where i.myId = v.myId)
  loop
    insert into vendor_history
    ( vhID, thID, Amount, Position, version  )         
    values    
    (mySeq3.NEXTVAL, mySeq.CURRVAL, j.Amount, j.Position, j.tmpVersion)
  end loop;
end loop;
```

I'm assuming the columns inserted in the second insert are from the VENDORS table; if not, the referencing cursor (i or j) should be used as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the currVal, it works with the following subselect.

```
   (  select min(thID) from task_history t3
       where t3.project_id = t2.project_id
       and t3.myID = t2.myID 
       and t3.version = tmpVersion ),
```

Comment: Danger!  Danger!  Are you sure you can't get someone else's data there?

Comment: And it'll fail in a concurrent load situation, as a row could "sneak" into TASK_HISTORY.

Comment: actually, i don't really need the min in here. i don't understand what you mean by concurrent load situation. the main tables have merge into statements and the triggers fire on upd/del/ins. also,  history tables have fk-pk relationship. you cannot sneak in a row without doing inserts to two other tables. it breaks the fk relationships.